# AdMob ads not coming in to view using UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, ios6, admob

I'm using the following code in my app (`viewDidLoad` method) to display AdMob ads:

```
// Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
// Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

// Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ABC";

// Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
// the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

If I use that code in another app or in the table view of this app (root view controller), the ad displays ok. Using it in my `UIWebView` and nothing happens.

Can anyone suggest what the issue might be please?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say you 'use it in you `UIWebView`'?

Are you adding the `GADBannerView` as a subview to your `UIWebView`? Because that will not work. You'd be better off decreasing the height of your `UIWebView` and adding the `GADBannerView` to some type of container view that also contains your `UIWebView`.

Basically, make the `UIWebView` and the `GADBannerView` siblings in the view hierarchy.